# Symfony change entity field type

Tags: symfony, entity

I have entity `MyEntity` and field `time` with type `integer`.
Now i need change field type from `time` to `DateTime`.

How can i do this if some records have `integer` value type in this field?

Comment: If you use the entities with doctrine(bundle), you should take a look at symfony-doctrine-migrations, this will help you migrate the database; https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#migrations-creating-the-database-tables-schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a temp field (Datetime)
- update schema
- run some logic to fill this temp field according to the time value
- remove time field
- update schema
- rename temp field and accessors as time
- update schema